# Zabbix not collecting data

Tags: linux, debian, performance, monitoring, zabbix

It's the first time that i install a Zabbix server on my dedicated server (debian 5).
But zabbix cannot collect data from the server itself (no remote server, it's installed on the server i have to monitor)

[image]

Do you have an idea on what's going on ?

PS: on the server, there were already a zabbix agent which allowed me only to see traffic usage on the server hosting pannel. Can it be related ?
I installed via :

```
apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-agent
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

things to check :

1. that zabbix agent daemon is running;
2. that firewall allow connections to whatever ip you configured for that local host on port 10050;
3. that ip used for local host in zabbix frontend matches the ip set in agent daemon configuration file, "Server" directive;
4. configuration->hosts in the frontend, whether any errors are reported for the zabbix server.

Answer (score 1):

Check your agent config file. If you've told the agents to only accept connections from the server IP (eg `192.168.1.1`), but the server is configured to poll itself via `localhost`, then the agent will see the local connection coming from `127.0.0.1` and deny it.

To fix it, you can add multiple IPs to the agent config, or set the server to poll the proper IP of the server.

A quick test is to run `zabbix_get -s localhost -k <key>` and then `zabbix_get -s <server IP> -k <key>` and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Debian, but I have successfully installed Zabbix with working agents on Ubuntu and CentOS. And @Richlv is right on the things you should check. Usually the server should be able to detect the daemon running on the same machine. From your case, it seems that this agent daemon is not detected. Try these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo service zabbix-agent status
```

If it says "zabbix-agent start/running, process xxx", then you could go ahead and check something else. Otherwise, run

```
sudo zabbix_agentd start
```

This will start the zabbix agent daemon, then run

```
sudo service zabbix-agent start
```

and check with

```
sudo service zabbix-agent status
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the server which is to be monitored check the agent is running or not

Check your agent config file

```
>vim /etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent.conf
>server ip : your ip of zabbix server
```

Then save the file and restart the zabbix agent

```
> sudo service zabbix-agent restart
```